# Problems running paster shell example.ini in Ubuntu while trying to install reddit

Tags: passwords, paster, reddit

When I try to run paster shell example.ini, I run into:

```
connection failure: TLEngine(postgres://reddit/password@127.0.0.1/reddit)
```

followed by a laundry list of traceback.

At the end, I get:

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "reddit"
```

Would anyone be able to help me resolve this issue?  Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [Reddit Setup Guide](http://code.reddit.com/wiki/RedditSetup) seems to be out of date or something. I had the exact same problem as you on two different machines.

Here's how I overcame it:

```
$ sudo su - postgresq
$ psql reddit
reddit=# CREATE USER reddit WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

I looked in the example.ini file and reddit/password was the default username/password for the DB. At this point, if you re-run your command (`paster shell example.ini`), it should complete successfully.

Fair warning, there are more problems with this setup after you get past this point, but I haven't yet conquered those myself.

Best of luck, friend!